# jQuery - Pause & Restart Interval on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are a few answers to this, but none that I actually understand.

So any help would be great!

**My Interval**

```
setInterval(function(){
   nextThumb.trigger("click");
   nextBanner();
   bannerLoop();
}, 1500);
```

**Clear Interval??**

```
$('#thumbs, #banner').hover(function(){
   clearInterval();
});
```

So when I hover over #thumbs or #banner I want my interval to Pause.  When my mouse leaves I want it to resume from where it left off.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearInterval()` does not  *pause* an interval; it *clears* it. You need to reinstate the interval inside the hover intent. This is particularly tricky if you use an anonymous function, so you'd be better to refactor your code as follows:

```
var intveral = 1500;

function intervalCall()
{
   nextThumb.trigger("click");
   nextBanner();
   bannerLoop();
}

var myInt = setInterval(intervalCalll, interval);

$('#thumbs, #banner').hover(function(){
   clearInterval(myInt);
}, function() {  
    myInt = setInterval(intervalCalll, interval);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign your `setInterval` call to some variable:

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
...
```

and then pass it to `clearInterval` function:

```
clearInterval( myInterval );
```

To resume it again you need to create new `setInterval` with assigned `myInterval` variable that will be visible in your scope.

So your code should be like:

```
var myInterval;

function createInterval() {
   myInterval = setInterval(function(){
      nextThumb.trigger("click");
      nextBanner();
      bannerLoop();
   }, 1500);
}

createInterval();

$('#thumbs, #banner').hover(function(){
   clearInterval(myInterval);
}, function() {
   createInterval();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create two functions to start and stop the interval, and to keep track of the interval ID:

```
var intervalID;
function startInterval() {
    stopInterval();
    intervalID = setInterval(function(){
        nextThumb.trigger("click");
        nextBanner();
        bannerLoop();
    }, 1500);
}

function stopInterval() {
    if (intervalID)
        clearInterval(intervalID);
    intervalID = null;
}
```

Then, you want to stop the interval when you hover over and restart it when you mouse out:

```
$('#thumbs, #banner').hover(stopInterval, startInterval);
```

Finally, start the interval initially:

```
startInterval();
```